# Play Boostrap Popover on loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, loops

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/0s730kxx/**

I'm trying to open Bootstrap Popover to auto-open on loop but so far I've have manage only to auto-play once.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" title="Header"class="myclass p1" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="Some content">Hover Left</a> | 
    <a href="#" title="Header"class="myclass p2" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" class="myclass" data-content="Some content">Hover Right</a> | 
    <a href="#" title="Header" class="myclass p3" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-content="Some content Yo Bestie">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var time = 1000;
var len = $('.myclass').length;
var count = 0;
var fun = setInterval(function(){
  count++;
  if(count>len){
    clearInterval(fun);
  }
    $('.p'+count).popover('show');
  if(count>1){
    var pre = count-1;
    $('.p'+pre).popover('hide');
  }
}, time);
});
```

Could anyone help? I want it on loop so it plays forever or atleast 10 or 20 times.

Comment: You can't clear the interval and expect the loop to continue! Instead of clearing set the count back to 0. But you'll also need to remember to hide the last popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify javascript part of your fiddle like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var time = 1000;
var len = $('.myclass').length;
var count = 0;
var fun = setInterval(function(){
  count++;
  if(count>len){

    $('.p'+(count-1)).popover('hide');
    count = 1;
    //clearInterval(fun);
  }
    $('.p'+count).popover('show');
  if(count>1){
    var pre = count-1;
    $('.p'+pre).popover('hide');
  }
}, time);
});
```

Since you are not clearing the interval in this modified snippet, it will run forever as you expected.

Comment: Thank You. Is there a possibility to show 2 popover at a time?

Comment: You can do things like:                                          $('.p'+count).popover('show'); 
$('.p'+(count+1)).popover('show'); But now, you need to take care of your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you have added line

```
if(count>len){
 clearInterval(fun);
}
```

After showing them 1 time count is 3 and `clearInterval(fun)` is called 
which terminates further call to  function `fun()`.

Answer (score 1):

Original comment: You can't clear the interval and expect the loop to continue! Instead of clearing set the count back to 0. But you'll also need to remember to hide the last popover.

```
var fun = setInterval(function(){
  count++;
  $('.p' + count).popover('show');

  if(count > 1){
    $('.p' + (count - 1)).popover('hide');
  }

  if(count > len){
    count = 0;
  }  
}, time);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89gcqnfm/

Answer (score 1):

Simplicity and modular arithmetic are your friends:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var time = 1000;
var eles = $('.myclass');
var count = 0;
var fun = setInterval(function(){
    if(eles.length < 1)
       return (console.log("No elements found!")&&!1) || clearInterval(fun);

    eles.eq(count%eles.length).popover('hide');
    eles.eq(++count%eles.length).popover('show');
}, time);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L2487dfy/

Comment: Thank you. I marked the other answer correct as it came ahead. Don't mind. May I know why there's a reason to use if and else statement since this is a static data and there would always be data? I'm still new and learning JS.

Comment: @ElaineByene, all good. I am using an if statement there because if the page does not have any elements with ".myclass", then calling `.eq(...).popover(...)` would throw an error in the JS code. That error would not be a huge issue, but in my opinion, it is always better to do proper error checking. Of course, the likelihood of there not be a ".myclass" element on the page is very low given that you have written the page with multiple elements with that class, but I put it in for the sake of best practices and such; however, it can be removed if you know those elements will always exist.